# Show that: $\sqrt[p]{A} - \sqrt[p]{B} < \frac{1}{p}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ denote positive integers such that $A>B$. Suppose, moreoevr, that $A$ and $B$ expressed in the decimal system have more than half of their digits on the left-hand side in common. Show that: $\sqrt[p]{A} - \sqrt[p]{B} < \frac{1}{p}$
Solution: Since
$$\frac{x^p - y^p}{x-y} = x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}y + \dots + y^{p-1} > py^{p-1}$$
for $y<x$, we obtain, on setting $x^p=A$ and $y^p=B$
$$\sqrt[p]{A} - \sqrt[p]{B} < \frac{1}{p} \sqrt[p]{\frac{(A-B)^p}{B^{p-1}}}$$
Let $k$ be the number of digits $A-B$. Then $B$ has at least $2k+1$ digits and so $A-B<10^k$ and $B>10^{2k}$.
Thus
$$\frac{(A-B)^p}{B^{p-1}} < \frac{10^{pk}}{10^{(2p-2)k}} = \frac{1}{10^{(p-1)k}} \leq 1$$
because $p$ is at least equal to 2.
I can't understand the number of digits of $A-B$ and $B$, and why we have $A-B<10^k$, $B>10^{2k}$. Can anyone help me. Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You don't define $p,x$, or $y$, nor why $A-B$ should be a "number of digits". Can't help unless you are much more specific.

Comment: Sorry, i missed hypothesis. Let $A$ and $B$ denote positive integers such that $A>B$. Suppose, moreoevr, that $A$ and $B$ expressed in the decimal system have more than half of their digits on the left-hand side in common.

Comment: Could you put that into the question itself? Some people may not look down to the comments for that

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. This is first time I post a question.

Comment: If A and B have more than half of their most significant digits in common, then their difference will have less than half the digits of A (or B), since all the upper half will cancel. So if the difference has k digits, then A and B will have $> 2k$ digits. If you still don't see it, take an example: take two 10-digit numbers which start with the same 5 digits and subtract them. The difference will have at most 5 digits (i.e it will be at most 99999 which is less than $10^5$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I really understand